# Hash with numbers as keys

Tags: twig

I'm trying to create a hash of month days (1..31) in twig:

```
{% set days = {} %}
{% for i in 1..31 %}
    {% set days = days|merge({(i) : i}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I expect to have something like:

```
1 -> 1 
2 -> 2
 ...
31 -> 31
```

Instead it creates a hash started from 0:

```
{% for key, option in days %}
   {{ key }} -> {{option }}
  <br />
{% endfor %}


0 -> 1
1 -> 2 
  ...
30 -> 31
```

I'm pretty sure that there is more elegant way to create a hash I want. Also will appreciate some explanation of unexpected output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `loop.index`. For example,

```
{% for option in days %}
    {{ loop.index }} - {{ option }}
<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It works, however I have to pass this hash to the macro which I can't change, and the macro has key and value loop

Comment: That is because use merge (in Php array_merge - http://php.net/array_merge). If you use numeric key, when merged keys, first key is 0, second 1... Use no numerical keys like '_0', '_1'

Comment: `code {% set days = {} %}  
{% for i in 1..31 %}  
    {% set key = '_' ~ (i)  %}  
    {% set days = days|merge({(key) : i}) %}  
{% endfor %}`